# Django Caught NoReverseMatch - TemplateSyntaxError

Tags: django, django-templates

I got this error, but can't seem to figure it out. I copied it directly from a previous Django project, hence part of the confusion.

> TemplateSyntaxError at Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'about' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

In my index.html, I have a link to `{% url about %}` didn't link to the about.html template

Urls.py has this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('django.views.generic.simple',
    url(r'^about/$', 'direct_to_template', {"template":"about.html"}, name="about"),
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was my second urlpattern was overriding the first pattern.

Instead of:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
```

it needed to be:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
```

Answer (score 0):

The url regex is expecting an ending slash. Does the offending url end with a slash?

If you do have a PREPEND_SLASHES settings differing from your last projects, that might explain the error you're seeing!

Answer (score 0):

Your url is ok. You need to check two things:

1. Is the urls.py included from the main urls.py?
2. Is the application added to INSTALLED_APPLICATIONS in settings.py?